# Pivot Table VBA problem - Same thing in Row and Value

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to make a pivot table in VBA that has the same field (Material Stock Risk) in both the row and the value, so it looks something like:
[Basic thing I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0aUS.png)

The problem is, I ALSO want a row for each project work order, so it will look something like this:
[End goal of what I'm looking for (shortened)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ6U5.png)

> **Risk      100**
> WO 1007    3
> WO 2834    7
> etc.
>
> **No Risk      7**

```
   WO 2439    2
```

> ```
> etc.
> ```

When I make my code, everything looks good to me, but when I run it, it snags on the second row column (Project Work Order) but weirdly, only puts that one. If I take that one out, it will put Risk in the row, but not the value. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you!!

```
   Sheets("Data").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Material Stock Risk")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Material Stock Risk"), _
    "Count of Material Stock Risk", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("PROJECT WORK ORDER#")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    *.Position = 2*
End With
Range("D4").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Material Stock Risk"). _
    PivotItems("No Risk Anticipated").ShowDetail = False
Range("D5").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Material Stock Risk"). _
    PivotItems("Potential Risk").ShowDetail = False
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Material Stock Risk")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
```

Comment: Add it to the values fields first, then to the row fields.

Comment: Well, you're a genius, and I feel rather foolish. lol! Thank you for your help. ☺

Comment: No - just been there before! :)